# Any better way to write list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to remove whitespace and 'the' from an artist name. But my list comprehension seems not readable.

Is there any better way to write this list comprehension or I just use classic for loop?

```
 new_list= [artist.lower().replace(' ','') if artist[0:3] != 'the' else artist.lower().replace(' ','')[3:] for artist in artist_list]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a comprehension with a regex:

```
import re
new_list = [re.sub("^the ", "", artist.lower()).replace(" ", "") for artist in artist_list]
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought of using regex. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You were right in thinking that if the expression in a list comprehension gets too big, it would be better to use a straight for-loop.

That said, the expression can be simplified by applying *str.replace()* to remove 'the' without a test (*replace* is silent if there are no replacements):

```
>>> s = 'The Artist Formerly Known as Prince'
>>> s.lower().replace('the ', '').replace(' ', '')
'artistformerlyknownasprince'
```

Alternatively, the whole process might be simpler and more flexible with a regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(^the)|\s', '', s.lower())
'artistformerlyknownasprince'
```

Comment: I think the first one will remove all `the`s, not only the ones in the beginning of the artist name (e.g. `Tom Petty and the Heartbreakers`). Also you are missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 2):

It's still not illegal to pull your tricky bits out into a function:

```py
def cleanup(artist):
    artist = artist.lower().replace(' ', '')
    if artist.startswith('the'):
        artist = artist[3:]
    return artist


new_list = [cleanup(artist) for artist in artist_list]
```

This has the big advantages (in my opinion) that you can test and debug the parts separately and that it's very clear what each step is doing.

BTW, you'll want to test and debug that cleanup portion right off the bat, as that approach will do weird things to They Might Be Giants.

Comment: +1; one important thing about good code is abstracting out implementation details, and working at the right level of abstraction.

Comment: Good idea, but note that it will remove the first 3 characters of everything that starts with `the`, such as `there and back again`.

Comment: @Selcuk I called that out. One of the nice parts here is that the asked can develop the `cleanup` function separately from the looping mechanism and tune it until it does the right thing an acceptable portion of the time. I mean, you *can* test the loop, too, but that adds one more big complicating factor into the mix.